# linking xml to an xml-schema (xsd)

Tags: xml, xsd

Im workinng with The Recipe Exchang Markup Language. My task is to extand XML-Schema (reml.xsd). After adding some new simple and complex types in reml.xsd i noticed that in my recipes.xml i dont have any "call" to reml.xsd. I added (like in exemple on http://www.w3schools.com/schema) :

```
 <meal name="Meatballs"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:SchemaLocation="reml.xsd"    >
```

But i dont see any difference after adding this lines.

Here comes my codes:
  .XML

```
﻿<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="reml.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>


  <reml version="0.5" language="eng" country="us">
 <menu name="Menu"><userData></userData>

  <meal name="Meatballs" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:SchemaLocation="reml.xsd"            ><userData></userData>
  <mealItem name="Swedish meatballs" servings="9" prepTime="30 min">
  <userData></userData><createDate>2013-09-26</createDate>
   <updateDate>2013-09-29</updateDate>
   <location locality="Sweden" /><difficulty>Normal</difficulty>
   <procedure>
   <procedureText>In a large bowl, beat eggs and milk. Add bread; mix gently and         stand for 5 
    minutes. Add beef, onion, baking powder, salt and pepper; mix well (mixture  
   will be soft). Shape into 1-in. balls.
   In a large skillet, brown meatballs, a d 
   few at a time, in shortening. Place in an 
   ungreased 3-q. baking dish. In a  
   bowl, stir soups and milk until smooth; pour 
   over meatballs. Bake, uncovered,  
   at 350Â° for 1 hour. Sprinkle with parsley.
   </procedureText>
   </procedure>
   <fb><usertext>Hej text från user</usertext></fb>
    <author name="Taste of Home " emailAddress="maxin@kth.se"/>
     <nutrition calories="399" />
      <ingredient name="Eggs" quantity-integer="4">
     <IUnit><IUnitArbitrary></IUnitArbitrary></IUnit></ingredient>
      <ingredient name="milk" quantity-integer="1">
    <IUnit><IUnitArbitrary>cup</IUnitArbitrary></IUnit></ingredient>
   <ingredient name="torn white bread" quantity-integer="8">
   <IUnit><IUnitArbitrary>slice</IUnitArbitrary></IUnit></ingredient>
   <ingredient name="ground beef" quantity-integer="2">
    <IUnit><IUnitArbitrary>pound</IUnitArbitrary></IUnit></ingredient>

     <IUnit><IUnitArbitrary>cup</IUnitArbitrary></IUnit></ingredient>
     <ingredient name="pepper" quantity-integer="4">
    <IUnit><IUnitArbitrary>teaspoon</IUnitArbitrary></IUnit></ingredient>
    <ingredient name="shortening" quantity-integer="2">
   <IUnit><IUnitArbitrary>tablespoon</IUnitArbitrary></IUnit></ingredient>
   <ingredient name="condensed cream of chicken soup, undiluted" quantity-integer="2">
   <IUnit><IUnitArbitrary>can</IUnitArbitrary></IUnit></ingredient>
          <ingredient name="condensed cream of mushroom soup, 
        undiluted"              quantity              integer="2">
     <IUnit><IUnitArbitrary>can</IUnitArbitrary></IUnit></ingredient>
    <ingredient name="evaporated milk" quantity-integer="1">
         <IUnit><IUnitArbitrary>can</IUnitArbitrary></IUnit></ingredient>
        <ingredient name="Minced fresh parsley" quantity-integer="2">
        <IUnit><IUnitArbitrary>ton</IUnitArbitrary></IUnit></ingredient>
    <category><CategoryArbitrary>Swedish dishes</CategoryArbitrary></category>
  <feedback><usertext> *Jag tycker bla bla * asdasd </usertext></feedback></mealItem>

    </meal>
     </menu>
     </reml>
```

Here comes my .XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
   <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"

  >
<xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en">
The REML schema for the food recipe exchange markup language.
Version 0.5, copyright 2005, Gary Gocek, all rights reserved.
Full permission granted to freely use, redistribute and promote
this schema.  Please retain the copyright notice.
When updating, add the new version number to the VersionType
enumeration. This supports backward compatibilty.
Home: http://www.sourceforge.net/projects/reml/
    </xsd:documentation>
</xsd:annotation>
<xsd:element name="reml" type="remlType" />
<xsd:complexType name="remlType">
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en">
The type definition of the root reml element.
The root element has the attributes version, language and country.
The root element contains the elements vendor, vendorData and menu.
        </xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="vendor" type="VendorType" minOccurs="0"
                    maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        <xsd:element name="vendorData" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" 
                maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        <xsd:element name="menu" type="MenuType" minOccurs="1" 
              maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:attribute name="version" type="VersionType" use="required" />
    <xsd:attribute name="language" type="xsd:string" use="optional"  
          default="eng" />
    <xsd:attribute name="country" type="xsd:string" use="optional"     
        default="us" />
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:simpleType name="VersionType">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:enumeration value="0.1" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="0.2" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="0.3" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="0.4" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="0.5" />
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:complexType name="VendorType">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="vendorData" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" 
              maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" use="required" />
    <xsd:attribute name="emailAddress" type="xsd:string" use="optional" />
    <xsd:attribute name="postalAddress" type="xsd:string" use="optional" />
    <xsd:attribute name="phoneNumber" type="xsd:string" use="optional" />
    <xsd:attribute name="URL" type="xsd:string" use="optional" />
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="MenuType">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="vendorData" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" 
              maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        <xsd:element name="userData" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" 
                  maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        <xsd:element name="location" type="LocationType" 
           minOccurs="0"                maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        <xsd:element name="meal" type="MealType" minOccurs="0"  
                 maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" use="required" />
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="LocationType">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="vendorData" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" 
            maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:attribute name="country" type="xsd:string" use="optional" />
    <xsd:attribute name="region" type="xsd:string" use="optional" />
    <xsd:attribute name="locality" type="xsd:string" use="optional" />
    <xsd:attribute name="useWhenCurrent" type="xsd:boolean" use="optional" 
              default="true" />
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="ScheduleType">
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en">
            A dateTime looks like   1999-05-31T13:20:00.000-05:00
        </xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="vendorData" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" 
              maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        <xsd:element name="nextPrepDate" type="xsd:dateTime" minOccurs="0" 
             maxOccurs="1" />
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="MealType">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="vendorData" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" 
         maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        <xsd:element name="userData" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" 
            maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        <xsd:element name="location" type="LocationType" minOccurs="0"
               maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        <xsd:element name="cost" type="CostType" minOccurs="0" 
                    maxOccurs="1" />
        <xsd:element name="mealItem" type="MealItemType" minOccurs="0"
                  maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        <xsd:element name="schedule" type="ScheduleType" minOccurs="0" 
               maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" use="optional" />
    <xsd:attribute name="servings" type="xsd:long" use="optional" />
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="CostType">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="vendorData" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"
        maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:attribute name="unitAmount" type="xsd:decimal" use="optional" />
    <xsd:attribute name="totalAmount" type="xsd:decimal" use="optional" />
    <xsd:attribute name="currency" type="xsd:string" use="optional" />
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="MealItemType">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="vendorData" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" 
         maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        <xsd:element name="userData" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" 
              maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        <xsd:element name="createDate" type="xsd:date" minOccurs="0" 
                     maxOccurs="1" />
        <xsd:element name="updateDate" type="xsd:date" minOccurs="0" 
             maxOccurs="1" />
        <xsd:element name="location" type="LocationType" minOccurs="0" 
               maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        <xsd:element name="cost" type="CostType" minOccurs="0" 
               maxOccurs="1" />
        <xsd:element name="difficulty" type="DifficultyType" minOccurs="0" 
              maxOccurs="1" />
        <xsd:element name="procedure" type="ProcedureType" minOccurs="0"
                          maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        <xsd:element name="fb" type="FeedBack" minOccurs="0" 
                 maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        <xsd:element name="author" type="AuthorType" minOccurs="0" 
                maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        <xsd:element name="nutrition" type="NutritionType" minOccurs="0" 
                maxOccurs="1" />
        <xsd:element name="ingredient" type="IngredientType" minOccurs="0" 
               maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        <xsd:element name="category" type="CategoryType" minOccurs="0" 
             maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        <xsd:element name="schedule" type="ScheduleType" minOccurs="0" 
               maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" use="required" />
    <xsd:attribute name="servings" type="xsd:long" use="optional" />
    <xsd:attribute name="pictureFile" type="xsd:string" use="optional" />
    <xsd:attribute name="prepTime" type="xsd:string" use="optional" />
    <xsd:attribute name="procedureTime" type="xsd:string" use="optional" />
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:simpleType name="DifficultyType">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:enumeration value="Beginner" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="Normal" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="Expert" />
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:complexType name="ProcedureType">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="vendorData" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" 
              maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        <xsd:element name="prepText" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" 
              maxOccurs="1" />
        <xsd:element name="procedureText" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" 
                maxOccurs="1" />
        <xsd:element name="location" type="LocationType" minOccurs="0" 
                maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="FeedBack">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="usertext" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" 
          maxOccurs="1" />

    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="AuthorType">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="vendorData" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" 
        maxOccurs="unbounded" />

    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" use="required" />
    <xsd:attribute name="emailAddress" type="xsd:string" use="required" />
    <xsd:attribute name="postalAddress" type="xsd:string" use="optional" />
    <xsd:attribute name="phoneNumber" type="xsd:string" use="optional" />
    <xsd:attribute name="URL" type="xsd:string" use="optional" />
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="IngredientType">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="vendorData" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" 
                 maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        <xsd:element name="userData" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"
            maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        <xsd:element name="location" type="LocationType" minOccurs="0"
                 maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        <xsd:element name="cost" type="CostType" minOccurs="0" 
                     maxOccurs="1" />
        <xsd:element name="nutrition" type="NutritionType" minOccurs="0" 
                maxOccurs="1" />
        <xsd:element name="substitute" type="SubstituteType" minOccurs="0"
                     maxOccurs="1" />
        <xsd:element name="IUnit" type="IUnitType" minOccurs="0" 
                      maxOccurs="1" />
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" use="required" />
    <xsd:attribute name="quantity-integer" type="xsd:long" use="optional" />
    <xsd:attribute name="quantity-numerator" type="xsd:long" use="optional" />
    <xsd:attribute name="quantity-denominator" type="xsd:long" use="optional" 
            />
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="SubstituteType">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="vendorData" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" 
                   maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        <xsd:element name="userData" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" 
                      maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        <xsd:element name="IUnit" type="IUnitType" minOccurs="0" 
                 maxOccurs="1" />
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" use="required" />
    <xsd:attribute name="quantity-integer" type="xsd:long" use="optional" />
    <xsd:attribute name="quantity-numerator" type="xsd:long" use="optional" />
    <xsd:attribute name="quantity-denominator" type="xsd:long" 
               use="optional"    />
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="NutritionType">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="vendorData" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" 
                        maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        <xsd:element name="nutritionItem" type="NutritionItemType" 
                     minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:attribute name="calories" type="xsd:decimal" use="optional" />
    <xsd:attribute name="pctCalFromFat" type="xsd:decimal" use="optional" />
    <xsd:attribute name="pctCalFromProtein" type="xsd:decimal" use="optional" 
                 />
    <xsd:attribute name="pctCalFromCarbs" type="xsd:decimal" use="optional" />
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="NutritionItemType">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="vendorData" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" 
                    maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        <xsd:element name="NUnit" type="NUnitType" minOccurs="0" 
                  maxOccurs="1" />
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" use="optional" />
    <xsd:attribute name="pctDailyReq" type="xsd:decimal" use="optional" />
    <xsd:attribute name="amount" type="xsd:decimal" use="optional" />
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="NUnitType">
    <xsd:choice>
        <xsd:element name="NUnitArbitrary" type="xsd:string" />
        <xsd:element name="NUnitEnum" type="NUnitEnumType" />
    </xsd:choice>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:simpleType name="NUnitEnumType">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:enumeration value="gram" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="g" />
      <xsd:enumeration value="ton" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="microgram" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="mcg" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="milligram" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="mg" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="kilogram" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="kg" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="joule" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="kilojoule" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="calorie" />

        <xsd:enumeration value="InternationalUnit" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="IU" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="" />
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:complexType name="IUnitType">
    <xsd:choice>
        <xsd:element name="IUnitArbitrary" type="xsd:string" />
        <xsd:element name="IUnitEnum" type="IUnitEnumType" />
    </xsd:choice>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:simpleType name="IUnitEnumType">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:enumeration value="bag" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="ton" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="barrel" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="bottle" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="box" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="bunch" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="bushel" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="can" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="case" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="centimeter" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="cm" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="clove" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="cup" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="C" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="dash" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="drum" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="ear" />

        <xsd:enumeration value="gallon" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="gal" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="gram" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="g" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="handful" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="inch" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="in" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="jar" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="kilogram" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="kg" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="kilometer" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="k" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="lb" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="liter" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="li" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="meter" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="m" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="mile" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="mi" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="milliliter" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="ml" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="millimeter" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="mm" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="ounce" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="oz" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="package" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="pkg" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="part" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="peck" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="piece" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="pinch" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="pint" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="pt" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="pound" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="quart" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="qt" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="shot" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="slice" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="sprig" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="stick" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="splash" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="tablespoon" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="tbsp" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="T" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="teaspoon" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="tsp" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="t" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="yard" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="yd" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="" />
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:complexType name="CategoryType">
    <xsd:choice>
        <xsd:element name="CategoryArbitrary" type="xsd:string" />
        <xsd:element name="CategoryEnum" type="CategoryEnumType" />
    </xsd:choice>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:simpleType name="CategoryEnumType">
     <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:enumeration value="appetizer" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="beef" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="beverage" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="bread" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="cocktail" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="dairy" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="dessert" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="meat" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="pork" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="poultry" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="sauce" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="seafood" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="shellfish" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="soup" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="steak" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="tofu or soy" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="veal" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="vegetarian" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="quick and easy" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="just for fun" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="picnic" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="winter favorite" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="spring favorite" />
         <xsd:enumeration value="summer favorite" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="autumn favorite" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="sports themed" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="super bowl" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="holiday" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="christmas" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="halloween" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="thanksgiving" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="july 4" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="new year" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="easter" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="hannukah" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="yom kippur" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="rosh hashanah" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="kwanzaa" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="breakfast" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="lunch" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="brunch" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="dinner" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="weekend" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="college student" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="ethnic" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="african" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="american" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="asian" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="cajun" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="canadian" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="chinese" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="creole" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="european" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="french" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="german" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="greek" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="hawaiian" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="italian" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="japanese" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="kosher" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="mediterranean" />
         <xsd:enumeration value="mexican" />
         <xsd:enumeration value="middle eastern" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="polish" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="russian" />
         <xsd:enumeration value="south american" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="spanish" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="thai" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="ukranian" />
            </xsd:restriction>
                 </xsd:simpleType>

          </xsd:schema>
```

I olso have an stylesheet but it was alrady with files and i have not done any changes to it so that why i dont post it. My files are uploaded so you can see how my recipes.xml looklike : http://dayoda01.hostkart.net/recipes(1).xml

My qustion is: What did i misunderstood? im prety sure error lays in my linking to XML Shema.

Comment: The Recipe Exchang Markup Language have a program REML.exe. With this program you can changes values of for example ingridients or change name of author. You can load in your recipes and then u give a path to XSD file on your computer. By looking at recipe with REML.exe you dont see lines like this :Ingedient: Name=Eggs, Quantity= 4. You see instead: Eggs 4. So when i see on web: Ingedient: Name=Eggs, Quantity= 4 i was thinking that since i dont have any path to xml schema then all elements from it is readed as pure text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you wish to provide location hints for an XSD that does not uses namespaces, you have to use the [noNamespaceSchemaLocation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256139.aspx) attribute.

Example (from the linked resource):

```
<person xmlns:xsi= "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://adventure-works.com/schemas/person.xsd">
   <name>John</name>
   <height>59</height>
</person>
```

I've cleaned up the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="reml.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<reml version="0.5" language="eng" country="us" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="reml.xsd">
    <menu name="Menu">
        <userData></userData>

        <meal name="Meatballs">
            <userData></userData>
            <mealItem name="Swedish meatballs" servings="9" prepTime="30 min">
                <userData></userData>
                <createDate>2013-09-26</createDate>
                <updateDate>2013-09-29</updateDate>
                <location locality="Sweden"/>
                <difficulty>Normal</difficulty>
                <procedure>
                    <procedureText>In a large bowl, beat eggs and milk. Add bread; mix gently and         stand for 5
                        minutes. Add beef, onion, baking powder, salt and pepper; mix well (mixture
                        will be soft). Shape into 1-in. balls.
                        In a large skillet, brown meatballs, a d
                        few at a time, in shortening. Place in an
                        ungreased 3-q. baking dish. In a
                        bowl, stir soups and milk until smooth; pour
                        over meatballs. Bake, uncovered,
                        at 350Â° for 1 hour. Sprinkle with parsley.
                    </procedureText>
                </procedure>
                <fb>
                    <usertext>Hej text från user</usertext>
                </fb>
                <author name="Taste of Home " emailAddress="maxin@kth.se"/>
                <nutrition calories="399"/>
                <ingredient name="Eggs" quantity-integer="4">
                    <IUnit>
                        <IUnitArbitrary></IUnitArbitrary>
                    </IUnit>
                </ingredient>
                <ingredient name="milk" quantity-integer="1">
                    <IUnit>
                        <IUnitArbitrary>cup</IUnitArbitrary>
                    </IUnit>
                </ingredient>
                <ingredient name="torn white bread" quantity-integer="8">
                    <IUnit>
                        <IUnitArbitrary>slice</IUnitArbitrary>
                    </IUnit>
                </ingredient>
                <ingredient name="ground beef" quantity-integer="2">
                    <IUnit>
                        <IUnitArbitrary>pound</IUnitArbitrary>
                    </IUnit>
                </ingredient>

                <IUnit>
                    <IUnitArbitrary>cup</IUnitArbitrary>
                </IUnit>

                <ingredient name="pepper" quantity-integer="4">
                    <IUnit>
                        <IUnitArbitrary>teaspoon</IUnitArbitrary>
                    </IUnit>
                </ingredient>
                <ingredient name="shortening" quantity-integer="2">
                    <IUnit>
                        <IUnitArbitrary>tablespoon</IUnitArbitrary>
                    </IUnit>
                </ingredient>
                <ingredient name="condensed cream of chicken soup, undiluted" quantity-integer="2">
                    <IUnit>
                        <IUnitArbitrary>can</IUnitArbitrary>
                    </IUnit>
                </ingredient>
                <ingredient name="condensed cream of mushroom soup, undiluted" quantity-integer="2">
                    <IUnit>
                        <IUnitArbitrary>can</IUnitArbitrary>
                    </IUnit>
                </ingredient>
                <ingredient name="evaporated milk" quantity-integer="1">
                    <IUnit>
                        <IUnitArbitrary>can</IUnitArbitrary>
                    </IUnit>
                </ingredient>
                <ingredient name="Minced fresh parsley" quantity-integer="2">
                    <IUnit>
                        <IUnitArbitrary>ton</IUnitArbitrary>
                    </IUnit>
                </ingredient>
                <category>
                    <CategoryArbitrary>Swedish dishes</CategoryArbitrary>
                </category>
                <feedback>
                    <usertext> *Jag tycker bla bla * asdasd </usertext>
                </feedback>
            </mealItem>

        </meal>
    </menu>
</reml>
```

With the provided XSD (and the hints as illustrated) I get the following error when validating it:

`Error occurred while loading [], line 53 position 6
The element 'mealItem' has invalid child element 'IUnit'. List of possible elements expected: 'ingredient, category, schedule'.
linking-xml-to-an-xml-schema-xsd.xml is XSD 1.0 invalid.`

Comment: Unfutunetly this did not make any difference.